# If no current is passed through, why does the voltage start off negative?

Tags: electrostatics, potential

The following diagram shows the graph of neuron membrane potential vs. time.

[image]

The above graph shows the case when $I=0$. In other words, the potential when the neuron is at an equilibrium state. Intuitively, I would have thought that I would see a horizontal line that starts at $mV=0$ and then staying that way for the remainder of the time graph.

> What is the cause of the initial spike before finally going to what
>   intuitively makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about physiology (even if that's the right word in this context!!) but if there is no conductance path, there will be no current regardless of the voltage.

Imagine a power supply that you plug into the wall.  It has a knob that adjusts the voltage.  If nothing is connected to the terminals, there will be no current flowing but you can dial in any voltage you want.

So for some reason, the neuron is in a condition in which there is no conductance path.